# Are there any plans, designs, or prototypes for an electric ground effect vehicle?

Tags: electric-engine, ground-effect

I have been searching around for any plans, designs, or prototypes for a small GEV. All I have found is a ground effect gas powered like this link:

or an all electric prototype for short distance travel (not ground effect) at this link (eviation alice):

Are there any ongoing plans to build an electric-powered ground effect vehicle?
Would it be any better or faster than the current water taxi or ferry services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary limiter is this: with batteries of current design, an electric GEV that can lift itself and travel a useful distance consists mostly of battery mass, with little useful payload. This is because a pound of jet fuel packs a lot more punch than a pound of battery.

Comment: so i guess if eviation alice short range plane is successful then that means there is enough battery energy density to do all electrics ground effect vehicle because high altitude flight takes more energy than ground effect flight right?

Comment: @user2177046 a good observation! Ground effect  flight indeed requires less energy.